# How to create an audio file from a spectrogram?

Tags: audio, spectrum, spectrogram

Is there any program for this? I can not find anything for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Coagula](https://www.abc.se/~re/Coagula/Coagula.html). I believe it is the same software Aphex Twin used in Windowlicker.

Answer (score 1):

There's also this project with some examples

http://arss.sourceforge.net/examples.shtml